# Unable to update an array of objects with another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two different arrays of objects, `storedArray` is stored in my file system and `inputArray` is made from user's input to update `storedArray`. The minimum length of each of the array is 1 and there's no cap on the maximum number. Also they doesn't necessarily have to be of the same length. So what I want is to loop over each array and:

1. if name from `inputArray` matches with the `storedArray` name and age is same, then do nothing in the `storedArray` but keep that object in `storedArray`. (example John).
2. if name from `inputArray` matches with the `storedArray` name and age is not same, then update only age value in the old object in `storedArray`. (example Jane).
3. if there is a new object inside `inputArray` with a different name that doesn't match with any in `storedArray` name, then push the new object to `storedArray`. (example Morris).
4. Must remove other objects in `storedArray` which does not match with `inputArray`. (example Joanna, Jim).

Update this

```
const storedArray = [
        {"name": "John", "age": 25, "courses": 5},
        {"name": "Jane", "age": 21, "courses": 3},
        {"name": "Joanna", "age": 19, "courses": 2},
        {"name": "Jim", "age": 20, "courses": 4},
];
```

from this

```
const inputArray = [
        {"name": "Jane", "age": 23, "courses": 0},
        {"name": "John", "age": 25, "courses": 0},
        {"name": "Morris", "age": 18, "courses": 0}
];
```

to this:

```
const storedArray = [
        {"name": "John", "age": 25, "courses": 5},
        {"name": "Jane", "age": 23, "courses": 3},
        {"name": "Morris", "age": 18, "courses": 0}
];
```

I tried this with `for of` loop but I get 22 results. And some of them are missing. Moreover, I tried it by pushing it into a new array. There are other posts here in SO with the same titles but the end goal doesn't match with my one. But still I tried their code but doesn't work.

Here's what I tried:

```js
const storedArray = [
        {"name": "John", "age": 25, "courses": 5},
        {"name": "Jane", "age": 21, "courses": 3},
        {"name": "Joanna", "age": 19, "courses": 2},
        {"name": "Jim", "age": 20, "courses": 4}
];

const inputArray = [
        {"name": "Jane", "age": 23, "courses": 0},
        {"name": "John", "age": 25, "courses": 0},
        {"name": "Morris", "age": 18, "courses": 0}
];

let newArray = [];

for(let item of storedArray) {
    for(let each of inputArray) {
        if(item.name === each.name && item.age === each.age){
            newArray.push(item);
        }else if(item.name === each.name && item.age !== each.age) {
            item.age = each.age;
            newArray.push(item);
        }else if(item.name !== each.name){
            newArray.push(each);
            newArray.push(item);
        }
    }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: since you want to remove every object from stored array that is not present in the input array, why not just replace the stored array with the input array?

Comment: because of ```courses``` property in storedArray. They have values which I can't change. If I replace it then the matched objects make all the courses value to 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) along with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the stored matching object. For each element in the input array, we try to find the corresponding element (with the same name) in the stored array. If we do not find one, we push the current element to the accumulator array. Otherwise, we update the age with the age from the input array element before pushing it.

```js
const storedArray = [
        {"name": "John", "age": 25, "courses": 5},
        {"name": "Jane", "age": 21, "courses": 3},
        {"name": "Joanna", "age": 19, "courses": 2},
        {"name": "Jim", "age": 20, "courses": 4},
];
const inputArray = [
        {"name": "Jane", "age": 23, "courses": 0},
        {"name": "John", "age": 25, "courses": 0},
        {"name": "Morris", "age": 18, "courses": 0}
];
const res = inputArray.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
    const stored = storedArray.find(({name})=>name===curr.name);
  if(stored){
    stored.age = curr.age;
    acc.push(stored);
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hey, why did you use {name} as a parameter in .find()?

Comment: also, can you explain briefly what you did there?

Comment: @Zak It's object destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: @Zak I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of updating the `storedArray`, just update the `inputArray`.

Map over the `inputArray`, check if current object from `inputArray` is present in the `storedArray` or not. If it exists in the `storedArray`, update the `course` property of the current object and return the current object in each iteration.

```js
const storedArray = [
  {"name": "John", "age": 25, "courses": 5},
  {"name": "Jane", "age": 21, "courses": 3},
  {"name": "Joanna", "age": 19, "courses": 2},
  {"name": "Jim", "age": 20, "courses": 4},
];

const inputArray = [
  {"name": "Jane", "age": 23, "courses": 0},
  {"name": "John", "age": 25, "courses": 0},
  {"name": "Morris", "age": 18, "courses": 0}
];

let updatedStoredArr = inputArray.map(a => {
  const exists = storedArray.find(b => a.name == b.name);

  if (exists) {
    a.courses = exists.courses;
  }

  return a;
});

console.log(updatedStoredArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could make the code more concise using ternary operator along with comma operator

```
let updatedStoredArr = inputArray.map(a => {
  const exists = storedArray.find(b => a.name == b.name);
  return exists ? (a.courses = exists.courses, a) : a;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the set of rules results in the `newArray` being the `inputArray` in which items `courses` take the value already in `storedArray` for corresponding items, a straighforward way to achieve what you want should be something like:

```js
let newArray = inputArray.slice();

for(var i = newArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for(let stored of storedArray) {
    if(stored.name === newArray[i].name){
      newArray[i].courses = stored.courses;
    }
  }
}
```

[edit]: the concise version of @Yousaf is the way to go.